# NodeJS Unit testing with Mocha, Chai and Sinon failing with results from previous test not being restored

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

In a fairly new project assigned to me where some code along with the test cases were already written, some existing test cases have suddenly started to fail unexpectedly with the stubs not being restored correctly.

The beforeEach and afterEach hooks of the test suite is as follows :

```
var getTokenStub, paramDescStub, getDataStub, getCaseDesiredAction;

beforeEach(function () {
    getCaseDesiredAction = sinon.stub(pgUtils, 'getCaseDesiredAction');
    getDataStub = sinon.stub(apiCall, 'getData');
    getTokenStub = sinon.stub(apiCall, 'getToken');
    paramDescStub = sinon.stub(paramDesc, 'getParameterDescriptionForCode')
});

afterEach(function () {
    pgUtils.getCaseDesiredAction.restore();
    apiCall.getData.restore();
    apiCall.getToken.restore();
    paramDesc.getParameterDescriptionForCode.restore();
});
....
```

This is followed by a few test cases which checks for errors.

**This should Pass with an error response**

```
 ....
 it('should respond with error if query fails', (function (done) {
    var req = {
        query: {caseId: '12345'},
    };
    getTokenStub.yields(200, '"Token"');
    getDataStub.yields(200, sampleDetailsResponse);
    getCaseDesiredAction.yields('error', null);
    getCaseDetails(req, res);
    res.response.errorCode.should.equal(1234);
    res.response.msg.should.equal('caseDetailsResult Failed while getting desired action: error');
    done();
}));
....
```

The problem is that even the next test case fails with the same errors as with the previous ones. For eg:- The next case too fails with the error `'caseDetailsResult Failed while getting desired action: error'` even though all the inputs for it are correct. If I comment out the test cases which check for erroneous inputs/states, the next cases work properly.

**This should Pass with a success response (But it fails with the same error from the previous test case)**

```
 it('should respond with case details', (function (done) {
    var req = {
        query: {caseId: '12345'},
        session: {
            "authenticatedUser": {userId: "999999999"}
        }
    };
    getTokenStub.yields(200, '"Token"');
    getCaseDesiredAction.yields(null, [{desiredaction: 'Close'}]);
    paramDescStub.yields('TEST CODE');
    getDataStub.yields(200, sampleDetailsResponse);
    getCaseDetails(req, res);
    res.response.should.eql({
        caseDetails:
            {
             ....  
            }
        success: 'true'
    });
    done();
}));
```

I am all at sea trying to find what is going wrong here. There are other files following the same format but they are not failing. Can someone kindly help me find out the issue with this?

NOTE : One thing to note here is that recently we added an async.map function into the original file.

**UPDATE : Here is the complete code snippet for the spec**

```
describe('getCaseDetails', function () {
  var res = {
      response: {},
      send: function (values) {
        this.response = values;
      }
  };

  var getCaseDesiredAction;
  var getDataStub;
  var getTokenStub, paramDescStub;

  beforeEach(function () {
      getCaseDesiredAction = sinon.stub(pgUtils, 'getCaseDesiredAction');
      getDataStub = sinon.stub(apiCall, 'getData');
      getTokenStub = sinon.stub(apiCall, 'getToken');
      paramDescStub = sinon.stub(paramDesc, 'getParameterDescriptionForCode')
  });

  afterEach(function () {
      pgUtils.getCaseDesiredAction.restore();
      apiCall.getData.restore();
      apiCall.getToken.restore();
      paramDesc.getParameterDescriptionForCode.restore();
  });

  // passes with error response invalid input
  it('should return an error if an input is missing', function (done) {
      var req = {
          query: {},
          session: {}
      };
      getCaseDetails(req, res);
      res.response.msg.should.equal("Invalid input");
      done();
  });

  ....

  ....
  // passes with error response 'Failed while getting desired action'
  it('should respond with error if query fails', (function (done) {
      var req = {
          query: {caseId: '12345'},
      };
      getTokenStub.yields(200, '"Token"');
      getDataStub.yields(200, sampleDetailsResponse);
      getCaseDesiredAction.yields('error', null);
      getCaseDetails(req, res);
      res.response.errorCode.should.equal(1234);
      res.response.msg.should.equal('caseDetailsResult Failed while getting desired action: error');
      done();
  }));

  ....
  ....

  it('should respond with case details', (function (done) {
      var req = {
          query: {caseId: '12345'},
          session: {
              "authenticatedUser": {userId: "999999999"}
          }
      };
      getTokenStub.yields(200, '"Token"');
      getCaseDesiredAction.yields(null, [{desiredaction: 'Close'}]);
      paramDescStub.yields('TEST CODE');
      getDataStub.yields(200, sampleDetailsResponse);
      getCaseDetails(req, res);
      res.response.should.eql({
          caseDetails:
              {
               ....  
              }
          success: 'true'
      });
      done();
  }));
});
```

Comment: The fact that your beforeEach and afterEach are defined outside of a describe block is suspicious... unless you aren't showing all the code there? maybe it would be helpful if you posted the whole file verbatim.

Comment: The beforeEach and afterEach hooks are inside the describe block. I have updated the question with a structured snippet for the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Your `res` object is carrying state from one test into another. You should initialize it in your `beforeEach` instead of directly in the describe block.